# Store and also display a ggplot in one line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I find myself often wanting to both name a plot and also display it. So I might do something like

```
require(ggplot2)
myplot <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() # store the plot
myplot # view the plot
```

Is there a more elegant way to both display and view the plot in one line? More elegant than `myplot <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + geom_point(); myplot` I mean.

Sometime I also do:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
myplot <- last_plot()
```

but that isn't really any nicer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use parentheses to print the output of an expression, which I've heard being called "printheses" if used for this purpose.

```r
library(ggplot2)

(myplot <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: (I have often included this technique in SO answers for brevity, but realize that newer users may not always understand what's going on ... and the enclosing parens live in perpetuity in their code :-)

Comment: "No boss, I don't know why this function has the side effect of plotting the data!" :p

Comment: This is exactly the kind of simple trick I was hoping would exist!